# Unable to create service in Amazon ECS using Application Load Balancer. No error message given

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to create a service on an ecs cluster with an application load balancer to run a task definition with two containers, an api, and redis. When I attempt to create the service I get the error, "Failed creation of service /n Service creation failed:", which doesn't give me any information on the error.

I would like the service to automatically register the correct port of my ecs ec2 by having the service create a new target group for me. My api container has host port: 0, and container port: 3000. My redis container has host port: 0 and container port: 6379, both using tcp.

I will paste the text version of my service configuration below.

```
Review

Cluster: rest-api-explorer
Launch type: EC2
Task Definition: rest-api-explorer:19
Service name: rest-api-service
Service type: DAEMON
Minimum healthy: percent 0
Maximum percent: 100

Configure network
Health check grace period: 10
Container Name: api-rest-explorer
Container Port: 3000
ELB Name: rest-api-explorer
Target Group: ecs-created-rest-api-service
Health Check Path: /api/rest/console
Listener Port: 3000
Path-pattern: /api/rest/console
Service Role: AWSServiceRoleForECS

Set Auto Scaling (optional)
not configured
```

Comment: Have you tried using console or CLI?  To try with CLI, you can go to this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/create-service.html and search for "Example 4: To create a new service behind a load balancer"

Comment: Are you able to run task without service?

Comment: Yes I am able to run the task without service fine, and also have manually registered the task to a target group and it passed the health checks fine, but it just won't run as a service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After attempting to start the service with aws cli, I've found that it was an iam permissions related issue. Lesson learned is that aws cli is better for getting error messages than console.

Comment: What was the permission your IAM was lacking? I'm running into the same issue currently ...

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this issue just add below policy to your IAM user

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "ROLE_ARN"
        }
    ]
}
```